# ggplotting multiple lines of same data type on one line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So i have this data, that I would like to plot onto a graph - all the lines on the same graph

```
>ndiveristy
 Quadrant nta.shannon ntb.shannon ntc.shannon
1        1    2.188984   0.9767274   1.8206140
2        2    1.206955   1.3240481   1.3007058
3        3    1.511083   0.5805081   0.7747041
4        4    1.282976   1.4222243   0.4843907
5        5    1.943930   1.7337267   1.5736545
6        6    2.030524   1.8604619   1.6860711
7        7    2.043356   1.5707110   1.5957869
8        8    1.421275   1.4363365   1.5456799
```

here is the code that I am using to try to plot it:

```
ggplot(ndiversity,aes(x=Quadrant,y=Diversity,colour=Transect))+
       geom_point()+
       geom_line(aes(y=nta.shannon),colour="red")+
       geom_line(aes(y=ntb.shannon),colour="blue")+
       geom_line(aes(y=ntc.shannon),colour="green")
```

But all I am getting is the error

> `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: ndiversity apparently is not a data frame. Trying running `class(ndiveristy)`

Comment: Where are the variables `Diversity` and `Transcect` form? They seem not to be present in your data? Also, could you post your data with `dput()`?

Comment: @VvdL class(ndiversity)
[1] "matrix" "array"

Comment: right, you will have to create a data frame from that matrix before using it with ggplot.

Comment: @Noah they are not, I will reduce the first line to
ggplot(ndiversity,aes(x=Quadrant))+

Comment: I did have a line of code to convert it to being a data frame, but I hadn't inputted correctly.
We got there tho
I'm still much better at the biology side than the coding side but thanks for your help folks (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, rather than using multiple `geom_line` calls, we would only have a single call, by pivoting your data into long format. This would create a data frame of three columns: one for `Quadrant`, one containing labels `nta.shannon`, `ntb.shannon` and `ntc.shannon`, and a column for the actual values. This allows a single `geom_line` call, with the label column mapped to the color aesthetic, which automatically creates an instructive legend for your plot too.

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(ndiversity) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = 'Type', values_to = 'Shannon') %>%
  mutate(Type = substr(Type, 1, 3)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Quadrant, Shannon, color = Type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

1. convert to data frame

```
ndiversity <- as.data.frame(ndiversity)
```

2. get rid of the excess code

```
ggplot(ndiversity,aes(x=Quadrant))+
                     geom_line(aes(y=nta.shannon),colour="red")+
                     geom_line(aes(y=ntb.shannon),colour="blue")+
                     geom_line(aes(y=ntc.shannon),colour="green")
```

3. profit

[not the prettiest graph I ever made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBs1z.png)